# Beta Distribution in PyTorch for a, b>1?

Tags: distribution, pytorch

PyTorch supports [Beta distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) however, when alpha or beta is greater than 1, it doesn't work:

```
m = Beta(torch.tensor([2]), torch.tensor([2]))
m.sample()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as expected using `FloatTensor` with `torch==0.4.0`:

```python
import torch
from torch.distributions import Beta
m = Beta(torch.FloatTensor([2]), torch.FloatTensor([2]))
m.sample()
```

Comment: What about mean and variance

Comment: They are correct. 0.5 and 0.05 respectively in the case of the example. Verify with `m.mean` and `m.variance`.